# How can I interpret the RMSE for small dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, dataset, noise, validationerror

I am training a network with 7 encoding (conv, BN, relu, maxpool) and 5 decoding (conv, BN, relu, Upsampling) layers.

The input data is a matrix of size 64*2000 and the output is a 125*256 matrix. The aim of the network is to interpret the raw data rerecorded by a sensor and predict the speed of wave in the corresponding medium.

I tried to train the network with 200, 2000, 6000 dataset. I use both validation (0.1) and test. No matter how big or small my dataset is I will be stuck with the same validation and test error which fails to predict the property I am expecting. I am expecting and RMSE of 10-25 and I get RMSE of 60-70. (the RMSE begins at 1540-1550 which absolutely makes sense and stuck in 60-70 eventually with any number of epochs or batch size or any optimizer.)

My expectation is that if I train my network on small dataset I get big RMSE on my test dataset compared to a dataset of say 30 times bigger. How can I interpret What I am observing here? Am I learning noise?

Answer (score 0):

Its a case of overfitting, beacuse your loss is too much in testing phase. Its a simple generalization problem. The main problem is with the minimisation of loss or RMSE . The problems could be anything like

1. The model configuration
2. Too less data
3. Too less layers
4. Choice of optimizer and learning rate
5. Data noise could arising in the preprocessing of images

So try to experiment with optimizers, initializers, regularizations, and try with other metrics too for judging your model.

Comment: The loss is not too much in testing phase, the loss is almost same as training loss (no matter how much training data I use) and it is relatively high. 

I'm not sure if this is considered to be an overfitting case because if I overfit I expect my network to predict the training data with a low error but it does not ...  

Training just freezes at a particular RMSE and would not proceed. (unless I run for many many epochs and then it overfits)

Comment: if your RMSE is not improving try tuning your model, experiment with other factors like optimizer, learning rate, momentum, initialization etc.